# Почему возникает исключение OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, сборщик-мусора

Работает пока GC не удалит объект, на который есть только "мягкая" (*monkey*) ссылка.

Два вопроса:

1. Почему иногда вылетает `OutOfMemoryError`, а иногда нет? Вылетает тогда, когда GC не справляется со своей работой или я что-то не так понял?
2. От чего зависит продолжительность работы программы?

Запускал на 3-х компах по 5-7 раз:

- на одном ПК работает ~150сек(всегда вылетает `OutOfMemoryError`),
- на втором ПК работает по ~450-500сек(иногда не вылетает, `OutOfMemoryError`),
- на третьем ПК работает ~60сек(всегда вылетал `OutOfMemoryError`).

На всех ПК по 8гб оперативной памяти.

```
public class Solution {
    public static Helper helper = new Helper();

    public static class Monkey {
        private String name;

        public Monkey(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        protected void finalize() {
            Helper.isFinalized = true;
            System.out.format("Bye-Bye, %s!\n", name);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        helper.startTime();

        Monkey monkey = new Monkey("Simka");

        SoftReference<Monkey> reference = new SoftReference<>(monkey);

        helper.callGC();

        monkey = null;

        helper.callGC();
        helper.heapConsuming();

        if (reference.get() == null)
            System.out.println("Finalized");

        helper.finish();
    }

    public static class Helper {
        public static boolean isFinalized;

        private long startTime;

        void startTime() {
            this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        int getTime() {
            return (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000;
        }

        void callGC() throws InterruptedException {
            System.gc();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        void heapConsuming() {
            try {
                List<Solution> heap = new ArrayList<Solution>(100000);
                while (!isFinalized) {
                    heap.add(new Solution());
                }
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                System.out.println("Out of memory error raised");
            }
        }

        public void finish() {
            System.out.println("Done");
            System.out.println("It took " + getTime() + " sec");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: По поводу второго вопроса - явно от производительности компа. Пока памяти хватает работает один поток (main). Но как только память заканчивается GC начинает постоянно собирать мусор и проводить дефрагментацию. Обычно используется ParallelGC, который нагружает систему по полной, вот тут и вступает в силу мощность компа. От этого и разница по времени.

Comment: Я тоже подумал, что от производительности компа, но от какого устройства конкретно? Чем комп мощнее, тем быстрее у него вылетал эксепшен

Comment: здесь несколько переменных, как минимум это размер свободной памяти, версия и битность JDK, работа JVM в конкретный момент времени.. если второе одно у всех, то первое и последнее точно будет всегда в разных состояниях, отсюда и результат не может быть одинаков.. то что памяти не хватает это очевидно, а при наличии 8 гигов, не факт что есть 5 свободных, которые занимаются выполнением этого кода

Comment: @keekkenen, 
 то что памяти не хватает это очевидно. 
Из-за того, что GC не справляется со своей работой?

Comment: из чего такой вывод сделан ? скажем у меня памяти хватает и не падает и из этого можно сделать вывод, что GC справляется ? очень сомнительное умозаключение..

Comment: Я понял, GC отвечает только лишь за уборку не нужных объектов, чтобы эффективно использовать выделенную память программе.  
P.S.Надо почитать про то, сколько памяти выделяется той или иной программе и т.д.

Comment: стоит разобрать с тем как работает сборка мусора.. сборщик в общем случае разумно устроен, не будет же он ради одной ссылки перетряхивать все, чтобы приложение периодически лагало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Дюк, вынеси мусор](https://habr.com/post/269621/)
Вот ссылка. Можно прочесть весь цикл статей, про все сборщики мусора, которые предоставляет Java HotSpot VM. Оттуда станет понятно, когда запускается сборщик мусора, как работает, и немного станет яснее о внутреннем устройстве разных GC.